# Old List questions, rediscovered

Tags: discussion, policy

Regarding [List of X/Poll Style Questions - What to do?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/list-of-x-poll-style-questions-what-to-do?lq=1) and [Re-evaluating "list of tips" type questions](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/re-evaluating-list-of-tips-type-questions)

I occasionally find some of these old list questions, as new answers lift them into the Review queue. There's nothing wrong with them inherently, & the 'list' aspect is well dealt with in the two links, above.

This one cropped up today - [Best webcam to use with Skype and a Mac mini?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30868/best-webcam-to-use-with-skype-and-a-mac-mini)
The new answer was OK-ish, so I let it ride, but it raised the question…

Should we flag these for Protection if the mere fact of them bumping to the top of the Active list is likely to attract a flurry of similar answers?
Or should we wait for the potential flurry to start, then retrospectively trim?

Answer (score 3):

Vote to close as primarily opinion based. The questions are no longer on-topic and within the scope of the site, and therefore should be closed.

If an answer causes an immediate increase in frequency of lower-quality answers and/or spam, protect it once you gain the privilege, but a VTC should be enough for most questions.

Answer (score 2):

I feel we should treat each question that gets bumped as if it were asked today.

- Closing prevents more new answers and can be easily overturned. Flagging might help if there's something bad, but the normal close review process should handle these.
- Flag closed questions for protection if you see one instance of bad things happening recently. (or if the item bumping it is flag worthy)

Delete might be strong, but leaving old crusty questions open doesn't help the site move forward IMO. I don't seek them out to close, but when they are presented to me in review or seeing them on the hot lists or the active lists, I generally move them one step closer to the grave if they are not awesome or in need of new answers.

Basically, if you can't edit it into shape or feel that it needs a bounty to attract attention - close it if it's not on topic or violates any of the current close reasons:

- Basic Customer Support
- Basic Troubleshooting
- Asking for Off-Site resource
- Too Broad
- Too Unclear